# Sorting and searching relation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

Lets say we want to find some known key at array and extract the value. There are 2 possible approaches(maybe more?) to do it. Linear approach, during which we will compare each array key with needle `O(N)`. Or we can sort this array `O(N*log(N))` and apply binary search `O(log(N))`. And I have several questions about it.

---

So, as I can see sort is closely related to search but stand alone sort is useless. Sorting is an instrument to simplify search. Am I correct? Or there any other implementations of sorting?

---

If we will talk about search, than we can do search on unsorted data `O(N)` and sorted `O(N*log(N)) + O(log(N))`. Searching can exist separately from sorting. In case when we need to find something at array only once we should use linear search, if the search is repeated we should sort the data and after it perform searching?

Comment: Sorting is not only about searching. You might want to iterate over an array in sorted order for some reason, for example. Not sure what you mean when you say _key_ and _value_. _key_ = _index_?

Comment: Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: There are endless reasons. My latest one was sorting a neighbour list for a graph algorithm. Maybe you want to sort some highscores, phone contacts, Google results etc.

Comment: Suppose you wanted create a set of unique values.   Sort first then the duplicates are grouped together -- no searching involved.   There are many other reasons to sort.

Comment: If you want to search for items in an array often you might want to consider switching data structures. Perhaps a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) of some sort, or a hash map. Sorting the array isn't really a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think before every search a `O(n * lg(n))` sort is needed. That would be ridiculous because `O(n * lg(n)) + O(log(n)) > O(n)` that is it would be quicker to do a linear search on random order data which on average would be `O(n/2)`.

The idea is to initially sort your random data only once using a `O(n * lg(n))` algorithm  then any data added prior to sorting should be added in order so every search there after can be done in `O(lg(n))` time.

You might be interesting in looking at [`hash tables`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which are a kind of array that are unsorted but have `O(1)` constant access time.

Comment: `n/2`, sure, but can you even say `O(n/2)`?

Comment: keyser is right: O(n) == O(n/2)

Comment: sudo_O: the distinction is made (as I'm sure you're aware) because lg(n) is not a constant.

Comment: Usually with Big O notation coefficients are dropped and only the highest order term is used but it's very important to know this. Given a small input what algorithm is better `O(100*n)` or `O(n^2)`...

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely rare that you would create an array of N items then search it only once.   Therefore it is usually profitable to improve the data structure holding the items to improve sort time  (amortize the set up time over all the searches and see if you save over-all time)

However there are many other considerations:  Do you need to add new items to the collection?  Do you need to remove items from the collection?   Are you willing to spend extra memory in order to improve sort time?   Do you care about the original order in which the items were added to the collection?   All of these factors, and more, influence your choice of container and searching technique.